# Tensorflow from source works slower than version installed from pip

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I build Tensorflow 1.13 from source, I noticed than it work slower than tensorflow-gpu installed from pip

1. GPU: nvidia gtx 1080
2. Driver: 410
3. Cuda: 10.0
4. Cudnn 7.5

I tried cudnn 7.3. I set path to cuda and cudnn in configure. With pip I have speed about 0.06 second and 0.1 from source
How I can fix it?

Comment: Have you compiled the source with all optimization options turned on?

Comment: I use this command:  `bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`. Also I tried this one:`bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both --copt=-msse4.2 --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`